# Mean.js, where do I start?

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

I have to make a web application with Meanstack for a school project. I have downloaded and installed the newest version of the Mean.js boilerplate (http://meanjs.org/) and got the sample site working. But I have no idea how to continue. There are so many files in the project directory. Can somebody please tell me the files I can/need to change to start building my own app?

I'm very new to programming, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'd really appreciate an answer.

This is what the project folder looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanjs.org documentation ([here](http://meanjs.org/docs/0.3.x/#getting-started)) has plenty of great information about what each file does, and what you might need to research to get started. Besides that there are a lot of great tutorials out there, one I liked in particular was [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4qzKky9B3ZymEqju8NIrsztgaHbRmJp6) youtube series.

Please note that in these examples I am using the mean stack from meanjs.org, not mean.io, and I am using version 0.3. If you are using a different MEAN stack, or version, I would still recommend first looking through the official documentation, and then various tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks for the Youtube link, I'll have to check that out. I had gone through at least ten different tutorials, but I always got some error messages that aren't mentioned in any way, like this one going through the Yeoman tutorial on their site: "yeoman Warning: (node:1644) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version. Use --force to continue." Using --force was the only solution that worked, although I read it shouln't be used. Any tips for that?

Comment: I don't know anything about that, what part of the tutorial were you on when you got that warning? What command gave you that error?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but it's not a problem anymore. I'm now doing the Bossable tutorial you linked, and I get that same message minus the `--force` part and it's not a warning anymore. It comes when I run `npm start`. It doesn't have any negative effects though, at least I haven't  noticed any.